# MQTT broker when send PUBACK packet

Tags: mqtt

Assume there is a mqtt broker , a topic has 10000 subscriber at QoS 1 called `topic_A` .Now one publisher publish a message on `topic_A`,how the broker deal this message?
I think of a way is:

- 1.save the message
- 2.send PUBACK to publisher
- 3.dispatch message to 10000 subscriber

  - 3.1 save one subscriber's message
  - 3.2 publish to one subscriber
  - 3.3 wait puback message from subscriber
  - 3.4 delete the message saved in 3.1
- 4.delete saved message in 1

but in step 3.Suppose the broker machine is powered off，at this time, 1000 subscriber push completed(3.4 is done),4000 subscriber is waitting from PUBACK(3.3),5000 subscriber haven't started pushing yet(not start 3.1).After a while the broker restart,how to deal with this situation？ How to set the publish `DUP flag`? Is the first one thousand suscriber need push once more after broker restart?

Answer (score 1):

The [MQTT spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800477) provides guidance on how this should be done:

> When a Server takes ownership of an incoming Application Message it MUST add it to the Session state of those clients that have matching Subscriptions. Matching rules are defined in Section 4.7.

The session state [consists of](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Ref362965194):

> ·         The existence of a Session, even if the rest of the Session state is empty.
> ·         The Client’s subscriptions.
> ·         QoS 1 and QoS 2 messages which have been sent to the Client, but have **not been completely acknowledged**.
> ·         QoS 1 and QoS 2 messages **pending transmission to the Client**.
> ·         QoS 2 messages which have been received from the Client, but have not been completely acknowledged.
> ·         Optionally, QoS 0 messages pending transmission to the Client.

So when the server receives a message it effectively adds it to a queue held for each client with a matching subscription (the message may be sent immediately if the client is currently connected). It's important to note that while the message body sent to each client will be identical the headers may differ (different message ID, possibly different QOS etc) and the server must adhere to rules around [message ordering](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718105). The server knows if the message has already been sent to the client due to the session state meaning it can add the `DUP` flag appropriately.

I thought it might be worth pointing out a few weaknesses in the algorithm you proposed because it helps explain why the above process is used:

- Its much more efficient to send messages in parallel; receive PUB, send PUB to all subscribed clients simultaneously (subject to ordering rules).
- If one client is disconnected (`cleansession = 0`) at the time a message comes in then the message needs to be delivered when it reconnects (your algorithm does not really support this).
- If one client does not respond then delivery to other clients would be delayed.
- How would the server coordinate messages arriving from multiple clients on one topic (remembering that message ordering is important).